# Wrong abstract page number and spaces between LoF and LoT with \addcontentsline

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, page-numbering, abstract

How to correct two things in ToC:

- Page number of abstract - should be "vii"
- Spaces above LOF,LOT and Abstract are big. Not like above chapters

?

Currently:

```
Contents

List of Figures       iii

List of Tables         v

Abstract               i
1 First                1
2 Second               2
```

Desired:

```
Contents

List of Figures       iii
List of Tables         v
Abstract              vii
1 First                1
2 Second               2
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand*{\term}{\textit}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    citecolor={black},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={black},
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}
}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}
\author{Author's Name}
\date{}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Abstract}
% \chapter*{Abstract} - When I use it I get chapter heading and abstract on another page
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{First}
\label{ch:first}
\chapter{Second}
\label{ch:Second}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to make it working with hyperref in pdf, that's why I left related code in example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `abstract` environment uses the `titlepage` environment, which resets the page counter, so you get page number i.

If you use the option `notitlepage`, you will get the correct page number vii.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany,notitlepage]{report}
```

Comment: ...alternatively, probably not as clean, use `\renewcommand{\titlepage}{\relax}` before the `abstract` environment. That is because, in the MWE, doesn't use the `titlepage` environment, but the `\titlepage` macro.

Comment: Thanks, finally I understand the reason of page numbering reset.

Comment: @Werner Thanksm finally I know possible workaround :)

Answer (score 3):

To correct the spacing above the "List of" and "Abstract" ToC entries, replace

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}
```

with

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
```

General suggestions: Consider to use

- the `book` class and its `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` macros (for roman vs. arabic page numbering),
- the [`tocbibind`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package (for adding "Lists of" to the ToC).

As the `book` class doesn't feature an `abstract` environment, use `\chapter*` instead. (EDIT: Stupid me -- just use `\chapter`, because `\frontmatter` turns of chapter numbering.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand*{\term}{\textit}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    citecolor={black},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={black},
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{Title Here}
\author{Author's Name}
\date{}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Abstract}

Abstract

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}
\label{ch:first}

\chapter{Second}
\label{ch:Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will experiment with `book` class later. Currently I will try to fix `report` setup.

Comment: Thanks to you, I've found `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}` is what i really need :).